# Get all posts with a duplicate name

Tags: hooks, title, bulk-import

I am running an import script which adds a large number of `product` post types. Some of these are identical apart from perhaps a `size` or `colour` value in the CSV.

My script creates the new post types (WP_Product using the WC_Data_Store) and ends up with what I would call duplicates:

```
post-name
post-name-1
post-name-2
post-name-3
etc
```

Is there a hook I can run to check if a post name already exists and if so, return it so that I can add the different `colour` and `size` taxonomy terms instead?

I would ideally need to check the `merchant` taxonomy as well as the post name as it's possible there could be 2 different products with the same.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it’s using wp_insert_post - if so, you could use wp_unique_post_slug filter... (or any other filter within wp_unique_post_slug function)

Comment: Would that allow me to halt adding a new post? Ideally I'd want to then call a separate function to perform an update on the original post (product) with some data taken from the new post that it was attempting to create.

Comment: How about using a custom SQL query to check if there's an existing post with the same slug? If it exists, update the post; otherwise, create a new post.

Comment: I assumed that's what Krzysiek was referring to - to use one of the existing hooks which presumably runs some similar SQL to what you are suggesting. At that point I'd want to intercept and update rather than add. Not having much luck with it as yet.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't referring to using any hooks.. What I meant is, something like this: `if ( $post = some_func() ) { // update the post } else { // call wp_insert_post() or use WC_Product to create the post }` where `some_func()` is your custom function for checking the slug.

Comment: Gotcha, simple as that - I can just check to see if the post name exists (with a few other checks) and then either create or update based on that. Thanks, no hooks required!

Comment: Yep.. but it would've been really nice if `wp_insert_post()` has something like `apply_filters( 'wp_do_insert_post', true, $post_data )` in the code. :)